# need correct scaling for boxplot using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, boxplot

I am trying to plot the following as a boxplot using gnuplot. Much to my despair, I am unable to get the scaling right in my graph.

```
65 804.0 827.0 832.975975976 842.0 857.0
64 797.0 827.0 832.329329329 842.0 857.0
128 894.0 916.0 923.955955956 931.0 954.0
129 894.0 916.0 923.25025025 931.0 947.0
256 1080.0 1096.0 1106.57157157 1117.0 1133.0
257 1073.0 1096.0 1106.38938939 1117.0 1133.0
512 1437.0 1461.0 1471.05305305 1479.0 1498.0
513 1445.0 1467.0 1471.5965966 1482.0 1498.0
1024 2168.0 2191.0 2200.5005005 2206.0 2228.0
1025 2169.0 2191.0 2199.74774775 2206.0 2228.0
1518 2876.0 2898.0 2904.15015015 2913.0 2929.0
```

Below is my code.

```
set style fill solid 2.25 border -1
set style boxplot outliers pointtype 7
set style data boxplot

set terminal jpeg large size 800,600
set output 'latency.jpeg'


plot 'finalresults.txt' using 1:2:3:5:6 with candlesticks title 'Quartiles' whiskerbars, \
''         using 1:4:4:4:4 with candlesticks lt -1 notitle
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "I cannot get the scaling right"?

Comment: BTW: You don't need to set `boxplot` options, because you don't plot `with boxplot`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plot looks weird because you have abscissae very close to one another. Is it expected? Do you want to present the box-and-whiskers at their actual abscissae or regularly spaced? In the latter case, change your `using` clause to `using 0:2:3:5:6:xtic(1)`. Add a `set boxwidth 0.45` also.